# Programmatically setting the stack pointer on MSVC and Clang

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, clang, system

Is it possible to manually set the ESP to an address stored in a variable on both MSVC and Clang without going through asm?

Comment: Why? But for starters, C or C++ have no "stack" as languages, it is implementation detail.

Comment: @hyde An implementation detail that exists in both msvc++ an clang++.

Comment: No, you can't. The stack is managed by the implementation. You can use `setjmp` and `longjmp`.

Answer (score 0):

Without ASM, I doubt it is possible. At least on Linux based OS either the libc implementation or Kernel setup's the initial stack. I think on Windows it is the Loader's job to setup the stack according to the information in the PE header. You could write your own Loader which setup's the stack as you want, but it is more complicated.

If you want to manipulate the stack you have to overwrite the stack pointer and frame pointer.

Here is an example program I wrote for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#ifdef __linux__
#include <sys/mman.h>
#endif
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#define NEW_STACK_SIZE 1024
int fn_newstack(int arg0, void *arg1, const char *arg2) {
    /* let's test the new stack */
    int stack_var = 0xcafecafe;
    printf("subroutine: 0x%X, %d, %p, '%s'\n", stack_var, arg0, arg1, arg2);
    arg0 = 0;
    arg1 = NULL;
    arg2 = NULL;
    return 0x66;
}
int main(void) {
    {
        int some_stack_var = 0xdeadbeef;
        printf("(OLD-)Stack var: 0x%X (%p)\n", some_stack_var, &some_stack_var);
    }

    /* grab some memory for the new stack */
#ifdef __linux__
    unsigned long *newstack = (unsigned long *)
        mmap(NULL, NEW_STACK_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
#elif _WIN32
    unsigned long *newstack;
    {
        HANDLE fHandle = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL,
            PAGE_READWRITE | SEC_COMMIT, 0, NEW_STACK_SIZE, NULL);
        newstack = MapViewOfFile(fHandle, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0,
            NEW_STACK_SIZE);
        CloseHandle(fHandle);
    }
#else
#error "Whaaaaaat?"
#endif
    /* Stack grows backwards. */
    newstack += NEW_STACK_SIZE; /* 1024 bytes available for the new stack */
    printf("New Stackptr: %p\n", newstack);
    /* 
     * Set new stack ptr and create a new stack frame.
     */
    asm __volatile__("mov %%rsp,%%rbx;\n\t"
                    "mov %0,%%rsp;\n\t"
                    "push %%rbx;\n\t" /* save old stack ptr */
                    "push %%rbp;\n\t" /* save old frame ptr */
                    "mov %%rsp,%%rbp;\n\t"
                    /* 
                     * It seems like Linux GCC, MingW GCC and Clang uses a different stack alignment.
                     * GCC Linux: 0x40 , GCC MingW: 0x70 , Clang Linux: 0x80
                     */
                    "sub $0x80,%%rsp" : : "r"(newstack) : "rbx");
    /* after this point all "old" variable can not be used directly */

    {
        int some_stack_var = 0xdeadc0de;
        char text[] = "subroutine with a brand new stack";
        printf("(NEW-)Stack var #2: 0x%X (%p), '%s'\n", some_stack_var, &some_stack_var, text);
        printf("fn_newstack returned: 0x%X\n",
            fn_newstack(1, &some_stack_var, text));
    }

    /* restore old stack ptr */
    asm __volatile__("mov %%rbp,%%rsp;\n\t"
                    "pop %%rbp;\n\t"
                    "pop %%rsp" : : );

    return 0;
}
```

Remember: This is a quick-and-dirty solution and not designed to  work within a secure and stable environment.

Compilation worked with:

- x86_64 GCC 6.3.0 with glibc-2.25
- x86_64 GCC 6.3.0 with musl-master
- x86_64 Clang 5.0 with glibc-2.25
- x86_64-w64-mingw32

Tested on:

- Debian stable
- wine-1.8.7

/* FIXME: I'm sorry, I currently do not have access to a MSVC compiler. */